# Timbre.js keyboard input doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to learn the timbre.js javascript library.  On the project page there is a functional preview of using the keyboard input to change oscillator pitch but once the code is copied to a new HTML document on my computer it no longer works.  Simpler code snippets from the project page work fine once copied over though.

The project page is here: http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/PragmaSynth.html

This is the code:

```
<script src="timbre.js"></script>
<script>

var VCO = T("saw", {freq:880, mul:0.2}).play();

var keydict = T("ndict.key");
var midicps = T("midicps");
T("keyboard").on("keydown", function(e) {
  var midi = keydict.at(e.keyCode);
  if (midi) {
    VCO.freq.value = midicps.at(midi);
  }
}).start();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for `T('keyboard')` and `T('ndict.key')` you need to include an extra script called `keyboard.js` which can be found here. http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/src/extras/keyboard.js

So your code will look something like this..

```
<script src="timbre.js"></script>
<script src="keyboard.js"></script>
<script>

var VCO = T("saw", {freq:880, mul:0.2}).play();

var keydict = T("ndict.key");
var midicps = T("midicps");
T("keyboard").on("keydown", function(e) {
  var midi = keydict.at(e.keyCode);
  if (midi) {
    VCO.freq.value = midicps.at(midi);
  }
}).start();

</script>
```

Comment: Wow.  I feel rather stupid now LOL.  Thank you!  Added the library to my code and it works perfectly now.  I had assumed that the keyboard input had been incorporated into the main timbre.js library and didn't realize it was its own separate file.

Comment: Yup. I had to look through the source code of mohayonao's website to figure out what was happening.